# Subsequent geotagging based on gpx

Tags: gpx, geotag

I would like to geotag my images based on a gpx file:
Preconditions:
- Images with time codes
- Gpx track points (with time codes)

Does anyone has a idea how add the images to the track points?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. First you talk about geotagging images, which is just adding exif data. Then you talk about adding the images to track points, which is going to be highly software dependent. Which are you trying to do, and what software are you using? You should also be aware that unless the camera and GPS clocks were sync'd with relatively high accuracy, matching based on time codes is likely to produce some inaccurate results if not outright incorrect ones.

Comment: gesetter offers a option to correct time difference between gps and camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows, I would suggest [Geosetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en/). If you are using Mac, I would suggest [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

Source: http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2014/08/geotagging-photos-using-gps-tracks.html